# AWS Copy instance and data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an AWS instance setup which contains mysql data. I need to copy this to a new instance to run as a development database. 
How can I copy the instance and the data? I believe the Create Image function just creates the setup and not the data.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks
Mark

Comment: I don't have access to the AWS dashboard currently, but I think you can save the data from a virtual hard drive and connect it to another machine instance.

Answer (score 0):

**aws ec2 create-image** should work - it will create a complete image of your instance, including the mysql data.  So *one way* to do this would be to create an AMI from the current instance, then launch a new instance based upon that AMI.